# Redirect joomla 1.5 RSS feeds to new onw via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, rss, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect old joomla 1.5 RSS Feeds to new ones via htaccess. For example I have an old URL: http://www.mydomain.tld/en/categories/debian.feed?type=atom
and wish to redirect it to: http://www.mydomain.tld/en/?format=feed&type=rss

I tried it with the following htaccess rule, but it didn´t work:

```
RewriteRule ^de/categories/([a-z]+)\.feed?type=atom$ http://www.mydomain.tld/en/?format=feed&type=rss [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^en/categories/([a-z]+)\.feed?type=atom$ http://www.mydomain.tld/en/?format=feed&type=rss [R=301,L]
```

did anybody know whats wrong with my rule, or did have a working one for me?

Comment: Which version of apache? In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query string is your problem - you can't match on that with a rewrite rule. Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=atom$
RewriteRule ^de/categories/([a-z]+)\.feed$ http://www.mydomain.tld/en/?format=feed&type=rss [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks that works. Can you help me to understand why? Did that have something to do with a previous declared: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.tld
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: This portion of your request ?type=atom is not part of the resource that your RewriteRule is trying to pattern match against. The result is the first argument of your RewriteRule can NEVER match against the actual request.  Testing the QUERY_STRING parameter separately and then the remainder of the request against the RewriteRule straight after such that both the RewriteCond AND the RewriteRule's first argument must be satisfied, it then works.